# UK student on exchange in USA travelling to Canada for Christmas

Tags: usa, uk, canada, j1-visas

I'm a UK student currently on exchange in the USA. I have a J1 Visa.
For Christmas I'd like to go and visit some family who live in Canada.
Other than getting my DS-2019 "travel validation" signed and applying for the eTA in the usual way is there anything else I need to consider in order to ensure my journey out and back does not fall foul of any immigration or visa rules?
Thank you!

Comment: Check (and monitor) Covid-related rules. Those can be tricky and are ever-changing.